# make MySQL store all numbers in English (Instead of Persian)

Tags: java, mysql, numbers, persian

When a user inserts a Persian number in a JTextField, I want it to be persisted in English format.
I can handle this issue in Java by converting the numbers manually before persisting. But there are so many entities (say 200) which each one has 10-15 fields. So it's gonna be a big pain to convert all these fields manually to English:

```
//before persisting the entity
person.setPhoneNumber(getEnglishFormat(txtPhoneNumber.getText()));
person.setSocialNumber(getEnglishFormat(txtSocialNumber.getText()));
person.setAge(getEnglishFormat(txtAge.getText()));
//...
//persist to db
```

The easiest way is to make MySQL to store all numbers in english by default. Does any body know how is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: Numbers have no locale format. What's the structure of your table ? I hope you're not using varchar to store numbers.

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but I don't think it is possible. I think that MySQL will take the data as is and shove into the database, so any normalization to the data must be done first (convert text to number, character encoding, map character).

Comment: thanks @nhahtdh. Sadly I think you are right! anyway I keep on searching, if i couldnt find a way, I would do the job manually!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have no problem if you do this :

- define your table using numeric formats for your number columns (not varchar)
- use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) for the insertion and use the setInt and setFloat methods taking numbers as inputs

Comment: thanks dystroy . I can't define the table columns as numeric since some coloumns have both string and number (e.g. 123gh14)

Comment: What's `123gh14` ? What would be a conversion to or from English ? This seems as a problem unrelated to the database.

Comment: in Persian number formats are like ۱۲۳=123. so ۱۲۳gh۱۴ must be converted to 123gh14 in db